# Carrots grown in my backyard look different

Tags: vegetables, raised-beds, root-vegetables, carrots

I just removed a carrot that I grew in my backyard. It is very different from the carrot you get in the supermarket. Wondering why the core is yellow instead of orange. The taste is not great either.

See pictures below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this Q/A](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/68039/are-carrots-dyed-orange) over at Seasoned Advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The outside is just fine. Supermarkets and the farms that feed them throw away carrots that aren't "perfect", giving the myth that there is exactitude to the shape of the carrots

The inside is a different story. Does it taste woody or too tender? It appears that the carrot is either too ripe or too tender.

You have to check your zone and also try to identify the variety you are growing to see what the right gestation period is for pulling carrots.

If I had to bet, I actually think you pulled this one too soon.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but an article defining this "perfection" I described above: https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/eat-the-crooked-carrot-save-the-world/2015/03/13/d6899452-c7fb-11e4-a199-6cb5e63819d2_story.html

Comment: It is likely I left it in too long. It was quite large when I pulled it out.

Comment: More than 2 months? Also, did it taste woody?

Comment: Taste was a bit bland but it was nice and crispy

Comment: Yes, crispy means it is probably hardened. Just to make sure this is not the only one, sample another carrot or two.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only had one carrot plant.  There is another one but that is still in the ground

Comment: We all make mistakes and sometimes, even when we do things right, the results are not what we would like. Hope your second one does a whole lot better and the next season you plant more!

Comment: Thanks @srihari!  I still don't know what mistake I made so I can fix it next time around.  Too much fertilizer, too little fertilizer, not harvested soon enough?

Comment: We don't know that you made any, unfortunately. Let us also wait to see if the other carrot turns out just fine. Next time, note the variety, its recommended planning and maturation time, and remind yourself on the calendar to pull it out on time.